# Aligning content in an HTML table

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, alignment

I'm just starting to learn HTML and ASP.NET I have problem with aligning content in a table.

Here is my code:

```
    .cartonTb
    {
        font-size:x-large;
        text-align:right;
    }
    .cartonlnkBtn
    {
        text-align:left;
        font-size:x-large;
    }

   <table >
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table width="800">
               <tr>
                 <td >
                   <asp:Label runat="server"  Text="MODEL NO" class="cartonlnkBtn"  />
                 </td>
                 <td >
                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonModel" runat="server" class="cartonTb" style="width:200px" />
                 </td>
                  <td >
                  <asp:Label   runat="server"  Text="MODEL VERSION" class="cartonlnkBtn"  />
                  </td>
                  <td >
                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonModelVer" runat="server" class="cartonTb" 
                                        style="width:100px"/>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>

                   </td>
                     </tr>
                      <tr>
                       <td>
                          <table width="800">
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <asp:Label  runat="server"  Text="PART NO" class="cartonlnkBtn" />
                                </td>
                                <td >
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonPartNp" runat="server" class="cartonTb" style="width:200px" />
                                </td>
                               <td > 
                                    <asp:Label  runat="server"  Text="QUANTITY" class="cartonlnkBtn" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonQty"  runat="server" class="cartonTb" style="width:100px" />
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Output in browser look like this:
[image]

I would like have a same start position for labels and texboxes.

I would like achive this look:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the widths of the td's consistent, and the contents should line up better.
Basically, make each

`<td width="25%">` or `<td width="200px">`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jordan's suggestion you will want `text-align:left` for `.cartonTb`

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you decided to use nested tables in the rows of your outermost table? If you were to use the following structure instead, and place your ASP elements in the `<td>` tags of the outer table (rather then creating new tables), then the columns would be automatically sized to fit the largest element from any of the rows, producing the desired results.

```
.cartonTb
    {
        font-size:x-large;
        text-align:right;
    }
    .cartonlnkBtn
    {
        text-align:left;
        font-size:x-large;
    }

   <table >
      <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server"  Text="MODEL NO" class="cartonlnkBtn"  />
        </td>
        <td >
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonModel" runat="server" class="cartonTb" style="width:200px" />
        </td>
        <td >
            <asp:Label   runat="server"  Text="MODEL VERSION" class="cartonlnkBtn"  />
        </td>
        <td >
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonModelVer" runat="server" class="cartonTb" 
                                        style="width:100px"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label  runat="server"  Text="PART NO" class="cartonlnkBtn" />
        </td>
        <td >
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonPartNp" runat="server" class="cartonTb" style="width:200px" />
        </td>
        <td > 
            <asp:Label  runat="server"  Text="QUANTITY" class="cartonlnkBtn" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCartonQty"  runat="server" class="cartonTb" style="width:100px" />
        </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

I have never used ASP before and so I'm unaware if there are any ASP conventions that would affect this structure.

And as Don suggested, you will want to change the `text-align` for `.cartonTb`